# How to extract content of Mono and set to a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have a function foo() that return `Mono<String>` I want to store the `String` output in a variable

e.g. -

```
fun foo(): Mono<String> {
   return Mono.just("Hello")
}

fun consumeFoo() : String {
   val result : String = // Set this variable to "Hello" by calling foo() 
}
```

In this case how to set result to string inside Mono in a non-blocking method ?

Comment: There are some ways of doing this (documented under "Going Back to the Synchronous World" in the excellent [Reactor documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.blocking)), **but** the point of reactive programming is to not introduce blocking code, but instead to use `Mono.map()` and similar to work on the value in the Mono without "getting" the value.

Comment: Exactly as @Jelaby said. Now, if you want to have the comfort of writing code more "naturally" via sequences of statements while still keeping it asynchronous behind the scenes, you should use Kotlin coroutines instead of this reactive framework. They are meant exactly for that.

Comment: @Jelaby I want to send the result as a body of an api request, how will I proceed without getting the string ?

Comment: @M_nikB You'd have something like `fun consumeFoo(fooResult : String) : Mono<Whatever> ...` which does your next call, and you'd do `foo().flatMap(result -> consumeFoo(result))`. Ideally you'd then add more `.(flat)map()` calls to process the result from `consumeFoo(...)`. Are you using a reactive library for *all* of your API calls?